Clustering a sequence of Bernoulli random variables
Let $Z_1$, ..., $Z_n$ be a sequence of independent Bernoulli random variables such that
for all $i\in\left\{1,..,n\right\}$ $Z_i\sim\mathcal{B}(p_i)$ where $p_i < 1/2$.
Define $\ell(x_{1:n}, y_{1:n}) = \min\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}1_{x_i = y_i}, \sum_{i=1}^{n}1_{x_i \neq y_i}\right) $.
Do we have that $(\forall x_{1:n}\in\left\{0, 1\right\}^{n})$:
$$
E\left[\ell\left(Z_{1:n}, x_{1:n}\right)\right] \geq E\left[\ell\left(Z_{1:n}, 1..1\right)\right]?
$$
I can show that the inequality holds for small and large $n$, but not in the general case.
